# h1 elements not appearing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying out react but my cdns are not working for some reason. My browser is chrome. My code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and in the main.js:

`ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>, document.getElementById("root"))`

Comment: You could just run `npx create-react-app project-name` with everything set up for you.  I'm assuming you're not integrating react into an existing app.

Comment: I am not but I would like to in the future

Comment: Alright, hm you might wanna try wrapping that html in a react component. https://gist.github.com/gaearon/6668a1f6986742109c00a581ce704605#file-like_button-js

Answer (score 1):

its a problem with the type of the script.

I replicated it and made it work with the following code:

```js
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Home</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" defer crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" defer crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js" defer></script>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/babel" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As stated in the react documentation you need to add a type="text/babel" for it to work with JSX. Here is the link to the documentation on how to add react to a website without a pre building tool. https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Edit: Also, please consider using **defer** for every script that you want to add to your site as it allows you to manage the flow of the scripts in a much easier way.